# LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear') output error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science, logistic-regression

I am using the logistic regression but no output is produced can you help me

this my code

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

loj = LogisticRegression( solver = 'liblinear')

loj_model = loj.fit(X,y)

loj_model

this is output

LogisticRegression

```
LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
```

true output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt5jq.png)

my output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVuAG.png)

I updated the python version libraries to resolve the error

It didn't happen

Comment: It's not an error. Your model and code are working as expected. The output cell of Jupyter is rendering it in a different way. It's probably because your using a newer version of scikit than from whereever that example came from. You can click on that blue box of output you get and drill into the details of the model. There's no error here.

Comment: I clicked but the details do not come, why?

Comment: There is a dropdown arrow to the left of the word Logistic Regression. Is that where you clicked?

Comment: yes but It isn't solving

Comment: By "solving" do you mean showing the details of the model? You also have the option of loj_model.get_params()